# Azure Load Balancing with sticky session

Tags: azure, sticky-session, azure-load-balancer

I have web API service which I planned to host in Azure environment probably in VM. 
My application is using sticky session and I have to enable the Load Balancer in Azure.

Can you please suggest best approach to load balance the application Or Can I use Azure Loadbalancer with sticky session other than Application gateway.

Regards
Abdul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the sticky session in load balancer rules with setting the session persistence as the client IP. And the steps like [this](https://cloudopszone.com/configure-azure-load-balancer-for-sticky-sessions/).

There is some difference between the Application Gateway and Load Balancer.

[image]

So if you will do some changes in VM, the Load Balancer is better. If not, the application Gateway is better and can be safer for web access.

Comment: Hi @Charles , Can you please let me know what changes you meant in VM. is it network related changes like IP address Or sub net changes ?

Comment: @AbdulAzeez I mean connect to the VM via RDP or SSH, for Application Gateway, it doesn't support connecting to the VM, just support web access.

Comment: @AbdulAzeez If the answer is helpful or for more help, please me know.:-)